# Facebook FQL how to know uid1 and uid2 are friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, friend

I tried this query

```
SELECT uid1,uid2 
from friend 
where uid1= 437574483052913 
  AND uid2 = 314664215408124
```

I got an empty return .
When I search their name in their friends list , I see they are friend.

Facebook depredated all the find friend ways .

Could I know they are friend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lot easier with the Graph API:

```
/me/friends/{user-id}
```

Of course both users have to authorize the App with the `user_friends` permission.

Comment: It is working . Another question , I tried to use Graph with this query /search?q=Someone 's name&type=user , But It didn't show all that Facebook Account , without any paging object . Could you give me another query can do that ?

Comment: could be a lot of reasons, some users deactivated the app platform, so they don´t show up at all in any api calls, for example. you can never be sure to get all accounts, but there is no other query for searching users.